# Is this safe for Parallel.ForEach?

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I have a service that pulls emails for parsing. Each email is parsed by multiple visitors (all implementing a simple `IEmailVisitor` interface with one method: `void Visit(VisitableEmail email)`. For some background context, visitor implementations include a SubjectVisitor, BodyVisitor, SummaryVisitor and so on.

The service has an `IList<IEmailVisitor>` which gets created once on startup, and then reused in a timer event in this manner:

```
foreach (var email in emailsToParse)
{
    foreach (var visitor in _visitors)
    {
        email.Accept(visitor);
    }
}
```

The Email class has this method: `public void Accept(IEmailVisitor visitor) {      visitor.Visit(this);}` As each visitor is visited, properties are set (or changed) on the email instance itself.

There can be quite a few emails to process. My question is, Would I be safe converting the above code to:

```
Parallel.ForEach(emailsToParse, email =>
{
    foreach (var visitor in _visitors)
        email.Accept(visitor);
});
```

None of my visitors maintain state between invocations of `Visit(this)`. I'm sure this question reflects my fairly superficial knowledge of task parallelism, but despite the reading I've been doing, I am unsure if this would be a safe approach (assuming there are enough emails each time to justify the operation).

Comment: "None of my visitors maintain state between invocations of Visit(this)". Now since the Visit method is being called parallelly, the above statement cannot be used to determine if it is safe. You will need to provide what happens inside the Visit method.

Comment: If all Visit does is set properties of the VisitableEmail and nothing changes on the IEmailVisitor then you are safe. If for example you are setting anything like Visitor.EmailsCount etc.. then you can run into problems.

Comment: “None of my visitors maintain state between invocations of Visit(this).” How does it maintain state *inside* a single invocation of that method? Does it use fields for that?

Comment: Most of the visitors get a list of parsing (regular) expressions from the database, but once set, this list is immutable and is the same for all emails being visited.

Comment: svick (and cheedep), I think I see what you are asking now. The short answer is no: state is maintained in the email itself. For example, the `BodyVisitor` has a private function `ParseRatings` that takes the Email and potentially sets its Ratings. Essentially the Email holds all its own state and gradually gets built up from visitor to visitor.

Comment: Please read this http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Thread_Safety you should be able to determine yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> None of my visitors maintain state between invocations of Visit(this)

If this is true, then it seems it is a safe operation.

If this method uses something external that's not thread safe then either make it thread safe or don't use parallel.

If one visit doesn't impact another then you're probably good to go with parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to mark my own question as anwswered because, as is clear from some of the comments, the issue revolves not so much `Parallel.ForEach()` per se but around all the you have to consider when considering multi-threading. The TPL certainly provides simpler constructs, but you still have to know what the heck you're doing. Time to study some more.